# filling list / Array by loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops, listbox

I'm trying to add selected values from list box to array or list 
and I'm getting a strange error

here is my code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> _AttName = new List<string>();
            for (int _i = 0; _i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; _i++)
            {

                if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                {
-> Failes here ->   _AttName.Add(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, false);

                }
            }
        }
```

or

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] _AttName = new string[listBox1.SelectedItems.Count];
            for (int _i = 0; _i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; _i++)
            {

                if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    _AttName[_i] = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, false);

                }
            }
        }
```

here is the error I get
[image]

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: just updated the post

Comment: Do you get the same error with the first piece of code too? Check that  `listBox1.SelectedValue` is not `null`.

Comment: yes ... with both of the codes I get the same error ( that attached )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** you will get this error because while binding the Items into the `ListBox` you have only binded the `DisplayMemeber` but not `ValueMember`.

So you don't have any `Value` associated to the Items in the `ListBox`.

**Solution :** you can use `SelectedItem` property to get the Item.

Replace This:

```
_AttName.Add(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

With This:

```
_AttName.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null && listBox1.SelectedValue != null)
   {

         _AttName.Add(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
         listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, false);
   }
```

Other solution:(Instead of using ToString(), use Convert.ToString())

```
   if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
   {
         _AttName.Add(Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedValue)); // Convert.ToString() will handle the null.
         listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, false);
   }
```